# Is there a tmp directory that gets cleaned when user logs out or logs in?

Tags: applescript, launchd, login

Looking at building a custom parser in AppleScript that would run throughout the day with `launchd`.  The issue I'm looking at is trying to find what `tmp` directory to store the parse at that would be cleaned after log in or log out.

After searching it would appear `tmp` directories are only wiped on the reboot.  If I can run a clean on log in or log out that would save on performance trying to condition when to run under a wipe.

When I research the topic I've found [Temporary Items](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4999116?tstart=0) that details:

```
path to temporary items
path to temporary items from user domain
/private/var/folders 
/tmp
/private/tmp
/var/private/tmp
```

but that doesn't mention wether or not a log out/in wipes the directories.  Diving deeper I found AppleScript has a tmp option from [Where to write temporary](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=33119) with:

```
path to temporary items from user domain
```

Searching the site I've found:

- [How long does the ios clean tmp directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47447/how-long-does-the-ios-clean-tmp-directory)
- [Saving /private/tmp](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166765/saving-private-tmp)

Is there a directory on a Mac that is cleans on a system running Maverick, Yosemite and Sierra that will be cleaned after a log in/out that doesn't require system admin approval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`path to temporary items` or `path to temporary items from user,local or system domain`: there is no difference because this folder is not in the home folder.

I tested this by creating a folder named "**xyz**" in the temporary items, log out and log in, the "**xyz**" folder was moved to the Trash.