# is it safe to delete /private/tmp vs /private/var/tmp?

Tags: macos, unix, filesystem

I see these dirs are bloated with size in many GBs.
I have never touched these.
Occationally I just delete `/private/var/mail/ishandutta2007`

Comment: Was it you? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166765/saving-private-tmp

Answer (score 1):

No.

No no no no no no no.

No.

Generally /tmp is cleared out upon reboot, but you should *never* just delete stuff without knowing for *absolutely sure* that you don't need it.

If you can't replace your hard drive with something larger and you're running that low on space, use a *reputable* tool that is specifically developed for the job, like [Clean My Mac](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac).